# Storage Cache creates files with different owner/groups?

Tags: laravel, git

I am using Laravel and it works well. After updating one blade file on my local pc and deployed it with git, Laravel can't open that particular blade anymore.

```
file_put_contents(/var/www/vhosts/***/httpdocs/memberportal/storage/framework/views/8274d2f145c8a134eb15ccbb69c2df396814d64e.php): 
failed to open stream: Permission denied (View: /var/www/vhosts/***/httpdocs/memberportal/resources/views/emails/newsletter/2019-04-2/translations/advertise/en.blade.php) 
at /var/www/vhosts/***/httpdocs/memberportal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:122, 
ErrorException(code: 0): file_put_contents(/var/www/vhosts/***/httpdocs/memberportal/storage/framework/views/8274d2f145c8a134eb15ccbb69c2df396814d64e.php): 
failed to open stream: Permission denied at /var/www/vhosts/***/httpdocs/memberportal/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php:122)
```

The folder permission and owner of the `storage` folder and `en.blade.php` are correct. However, I noticed that the owner/group of the files in the cache are different.

All caches files with owner `root:root` are not accessible. Any ideas why Laravel changes the ownership of cache files on my production server, when deploying with git? The storage files are ignored by git, so I do not understand how this happens.

Any advice?

Comment: may be you need to use `php artisan cache:clear` and `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu yes that would fix it. But my question is, why did the owner change when deploying with git.

Comment: I think you have pulled your code to your server with different users, I faced such situation with root vs ubuntu.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the cache file ownership depends on the user that executes the caching command, so I guess you should review your deployment process to see when the caché files are created and what user is running the deployment scripts at that step

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu I pull via webhook automatically. So there is no user doing a pull.

Comment: @Adam https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7295 may give you better idea on it.

Comment: is the git user the same as the apache/nginx user?? If not than it is normal where you have to set a post command to change owner to web user..

Comment: @Adam specially this comment https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/7295#issuecomment-119627421

Comment: @Alpy yes its the same user. Also this does not happen always. If I change a file and deploy it with git it works most of the time. Just in very rare cases the owner of a cache file is changed.

Comment: @Adam changed to which user?? root??